# elements in two maximal ideals that have sum 1

Tags: ring-theory

consider $R'=Q[x]$. ideals $I'=(x-2)$ and $J'=(x-5)$ are maximal and so there are elements in $I'$ and $J'$ such that their sum is 1. it is easy to find them: $1/3 (x-2) - 1/3 (x-5)=1$.

Now let $R$ be the subring of $R'$ that consist of polynomials that their evaluation at 0 is an element of $Z$. again $I=(x-2)$ and $J=(x-5)$ are maximal. but i can not find elements in $I$ and $J$ such that their sum is 1, since 1/3 is not in $Z$.

can you help?

Comment: Try finding "simple" polynomials $f,g$ in $R'$ such that $f(x)(x-2)+g(x)(x-5) = 1$ and it will boil down to solving a system of equations.

Comment: tanx. what is  "simple" polynomials "?

Comment: I'd start with linear polynomials

Comment: Thank you. i got it. should i delete the question or accept your answer?

Comment: It would be best if you answered your own question and accepted it. This way future askers can also benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Arkady suggests,  I answer my own question (by the comments) and accepted it:

---

We want to have $(ax+b)(x-2)+(cx+d)(x-5) = 1$, for suitable $a,b,c,d$.
or equivalently, $(a+c)x^2 +(b-2a+d -5c)x - (2b+5d)=1$.
solving the  system of equations : $$a+c=0 ,\ b-2a+d -5c=0,\ 2b+5d=-1$$
we have $a=-c= 10/15,\ b=-3,\ d=1$.